# Redis Batch Updating Dictionaries

Tags: python, redis

So I have inserted a bunch of key:dict in redis, as follows:

```
{user1 : {command1:0, command2:0}}
```

etc. Every time a user uses a command, it increases the counter by 1, and it resets every hour.

However, I was reading up on redis and this would mean that for the batch update to reset,  I would have to do a KEY search and then update each one individually. I understand I can use a pipeline to do so as well so I can bulk-update every one of them.

Is there a better method of doing so? There’s usually about 100k users and it can expand up to lets say a million, is this safe/effective enough and would the query be short enough for production?

Because I feel like if I had this information on a DB - I could just do something like “UPDATE table SET command1 = 0 WHERE command1 != 0”, but that means that everytime a command is used (usually about 100/s) I would need to update it...

Answer (score 0):

you dont' need to insert the commands in advance.

Just use [HINCRBY](https://redis.io/commands/hincrby) command

Let's say redis is empty,now you issue

```
HINCRBY user1  command1 1
```

Redis will create a hash called user1, with a field command1, and 1 as its value.

Do this again

```
HINCRBY user1  command1 1
```

Then

```
HGET user1  command1
```

You get 2 as result

To reset the counter, just delete user1.
Then if you issue this command immeditely (query the counter)

```
HGET user1  command1
```

you get 0 or null as result (depends on your Redis client)

With one million customers and 100 commands each, it will be a few hundred MBs of storage .

Redis will take about 50K QPS (single instance) ~ 150K QPS (clusters). So you can do the math and see if it's enough, depends on how many customers are issuing commands at once.